# Bash: Executing a complex command in a string, capturing output and return code

Tags: bash, shell

I want to execute a command that is in a string in bash, and capture the output and exit code.

I've googled around a bit and searched on here, but I'm not getting a clear result for this. The [Bash FAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) which is referred a lot, is largely a condescending attempt to disuade people from doing it. For example one of my reasons is logging, but echoing commands to terminal using `set -x` isn't logging, and the output for complicated commands is excessive and unintuitive when all I want is to be certain that I've logged the exact command my scripts ran, and not a copy & paste that will fail to be updated at some point down the road `</rant>`. The reason I'm explaining this in detail is that most of the questions on this topic get shut down as duplicates, but the specific requirements of executing a string AND capturing the output don't seem to be represented.

Here is a simplified example.

```
CMD="echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2"
```

The output should just be `b`. Now what I want is the return code (`EXITCODE=$?`) and the output. This seemed to me like a straight forward case, but I just can't get there. Things I've tried from googling on this (these are all things found online):

```
OUTPUT=eval $CMD    # "", ec 0  , note: $CMD is echoed to shell
OUTPUT=eval "$CMD"  # "", ec 127, note: command not found
OUTPUT=eval $($CMD) # "", ec 127, note: command not found
OUTPUT=$("$CMD")    # "", ec 127, note: command not found
OUTPUT=`$CMD`       # "echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2", ec 0
OUTPUT=$($CMD)      # "echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2", ec 0
OUTPUT="$($CMD)"    # "echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2", ec 0
OUTPUT=$CMD         # "echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2", ec 0
OUTPUT=${CMD}       # "echo 'a*b*c' | cut -d '*' -f 2", ec 0
OUTPUT=${$CMD}      # "", ec 0, note: bad substitution
OUTPUT=${!CMD}      # "", ec 0
TEST=($CMD)
OUTPUT=eval $TEST   # "", ec 0
```

I'm sure I missed some other attempts. Is bash really not capable of performing such a basic task as executing a command in a string and letting me capture the output without some really ugly hacking (like redirecting output to a file and reading that)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of defining a function?

Comment: @chepner Because I can't for example log the command if I use a function. (Unless there's some clever way to achieve that?) I specifically don't want a line that logs the command and another function or otherwise that executes it as the chance of one but not the other getting updated later is worrying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I was painstakingly going through typing up all this question, I finally thought of a working solution, which in hindsight is rather simple:

```
OUTPUT=$(eval "$CMD")
EXITCODE=$?
```

Since I've already typed all this out and was unable to google for this myself, I figured I'd just post this and let it be.